# Can I connect two bluetooth device to my tablet?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, tablet

I would like to connect a bluetooth keyboard and bluetooth mouse to my tablet. Is it possible at the same time?

Comment: This depends on solely on the device and the Bluetooth antenna. Bluetooth works similar to WiFi (talk/air time, MAC addresses etc.) so usually you can connect multiple devices to a single host. Have you tried connecting multiple devices at once?

Comment: There may be a long answer as well, but your question is vague as you don't specify the devices you are using. What tablet? What mouse and keyboard? There are very few devices (mostly just headphone hubs) that can support multiple simultaneous connections.

Comment: please consider adding further informations ,like tablet model ,android version

Comment: The tablet is an [ASUS MemoPad HD 7](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_memo_pad_hd7_16_gb-5492.php) and runs the factory android 4.2. I would like to use a case with bluetooth keyboard and if it is possibel i want to buy a bluetooth mouse too.

Comment: Hey OP- don't forget to select an answer below if it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I honestly thought that only one device could be connected at a time using Bluetooth. In an attempt to prove my point I tested connecting multiple devices simultaneously to my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4:

[image: IMG:]

Sure enough I was able to stream music to my Milwaukee speaker while using an Apple mouse and keyboard- all connected at the same time. Granted, there are probably still instances where this might not work depending on devices and most likely would only be able to stream music to a single device, but it worked perfectly in this case.

Comment: That's not true. One master (tablet or smartphone) can communicate with up to 7 slaves. You can easily be connected to a smartwatch and headset/car at the same time.

Comment: @Alex You are only partly correct, especially when considering the hardware in question. The ASUS MemoPad HD 7, as the OP eventually informed, has Bluetooth 4.0. The specs on most devices using Bluetooth 4.0 use dual-mode radios. This essentially does allow the phone/tablet to be connected to two Bluetooth devices simultaneously, but only certain devices. The dual-mode radio allows connection to one Bluetooth 4.0 low-energy device, for instance your smartwatch, and one "classic" device like a headset. This seems to be the limit. However, I will test this theory later today myself to make sure.

Comment: @Alex.S - I stand corrected and changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly on my phone I have two Bluetooth devices connected simultaneously - my watch and headset.  It really depends both on the host device (the tablet) and to some extent on the  peripheral ie the mouse and keyboard.